# Can not connect via RDP to computer when VPN connection is established

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, routing, cisco-anyconnect

I need to be able to use RDP to connect to computer with VPN (Cisco Any connect client) connection established. There are lots of closely related discussions on the Internet, however, being a regular user without any knowledge of network administration, I have been unable to adapt any of the solutions to my case (the «Allow local (LAN) access when using VPN (if configured)» check-box is, of course, on, which doesn't make any difference and contacting VPN-server administrators to get it working, i. e. enabling split-tunneling, is out of the question).

I gather the problem has everything to do with network routing (not sure whether it can be solved at all).

The «route print» command gives me the following lines amongst others:

```
  192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.189     26
  192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0        10.44.0.1      10.44.7.140      2
```

As far as I understand (please, correct me in case I am wrong) it is the second line that bears responsibility for the fact I can not connect remotely to the computer when VPN ist on. I tried to delete the line without any success. It just reappearrs. Please, advise me on what to try next.